# Amazon SNS vs Firebase pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

We have to decide for a option to send Push notifications to our app. We are considering either of Amazon SNS or Firebase. While listing down the pros and cons of each, I could only find the pricing or cap on notifications for Amazon SNS which is:

> It offers 1 year of free resources, but is chargable later on.
>   Currently the first million of Amazon SNS requests per month are free.
>   Then every additional million of Amazon SNS requests costs 0.50 USD.

However I could not find anything of this sort for Firebase. Is there a limitation on the number of notifications that can be sent out for free and will be chargeable after a certain number is crossed? If yes than what are the costs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does AWS SNS anyway require other providers, like FCM, for sending the mobile app notifications? [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no limit on the number of messages that can be sent with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/):

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean any number of notifications can be sent if we use the free plan for Firebase?

Comment: Yes. There is no limit on the number of messages that can be sent with Firebase Cloud Messaging.